# What does "First Load JS" in @next/bundle-analyzer actually measure?

Tags: javascript, next.js

The NextJS bundle analyzer gives some output like this:

```
Page                                                                         Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                                                        12 kB           368 kB
├   └ 79.202101.46dabc.chunk.css                                             10.3 kB
...
+ First Load JS shared by all                                                195 kB
  ├ chunks/0e69992b3e9a8d51f37748cf97b75268d47a0f0c.f372af.js                27.6 kB
  ├ chunks/cf0e5769c2fa5761a95adfa95a4e062fb86f8f05.272397.js                91.4 kB
  ├ chunks/commons.9707f2.js                                                 9.01 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.efaa9a.js                                               46.9 kB
  ├ chunks/main.9965a5.js                                                    6.39 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.a4ce0d.js                                              11.4 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack.8e3a04.js                                                 2.72 kB
  └ 62.202101.796f1f.chunk.css                                               3.7 kB
```

What exactly does "First Load JS" measure and why does it not equal the sum of "First Load JS shared by all" and the size of the page and it's sub-pages. I.e. based on this output I would expect First Load JS to equal 12 kb + 10.3 kb + 195 kb, not 368 kb.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the default output from running `next build`, it doesn't come from `@next/bundle-analyzer`. As you mention, the "First Load JS" value for each page should be equal to "First Load JS shared by all" + that page's size. Can you share the full output?

Comment: Taking over for Eric here. @juliomalves, you're right. If we turn off the ANALYZE_BUNDLE=true env param we get the same output without the heatmaps. So the output is not from the analyzer, it's from the build. The question still stands. Why don't the numbers add up? Here's the full output: https://gist.github.com/thelinuxkid/6eaa9505acb0630c621e0d4adf634cca

Answer (score 8):

Here's what the docs say:

> **Size** – The number of assets downloaded when navigating to the page client-side. The size for each route only includes its dependencies.
>
> **First Load JS** – The number of assets downloaded when visiting the page from the server. The amount of JS shared by all is shown as a
> separate metric.

If you're reading the above and annoyed by the circular references, you're not alone. The output is extra confusing in your case because you only have one route listed (though presumably more you cut off), but the docs do, somewhat helpfully, note that "the output displays information about each route."

Basically, when a user hits the site the first time, they'll download the `First Load JS` for their requested route from the server first, then start loading additional assets client-side as the page renders.

The UX of this output is super confusing, but once you understand the terms, the numbers actually do add up.

`First Load JS shared by all`, in contrast, refers to JS assets shared across (and loaded when visiting) every single route. In your case, First Load JS shared by all = 195KB, which is (approximately) equal to (27.6+91.4+9.01+46.9+6.39+11.4+2.72) ... the css apparently isn't included, (I guess for the sole reason that it's not JS, which seems dumb, but whatever).

The point of the "shared by all" metric is that if you can reduce that number you'll reduce the amount your users have to download on every single route, so it's ostensibly a good place to start optimizing.

If all of the above is still confusing, a clearer output might be:

| Page | Route-Specific Client-Side | Route-Specific Server-Side | Total Server-Side | Total (Server + Client) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| / | 12KB | 161KB (368KB - 195KB - 12KB) | 356KB (368KB - 12KB) | 368KB |

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. You haven't actually explained the numbers. Yes, the "First Load JS shared by all" equals the sum of its components.

Comment: What exactly extra is loaded in First Load JS that is not accounted for in First Load JS shared by all?

Comment: @EricConner - Anything unique to that route that isn't loaded client-side.

For example, any page-specific logic would likely fall under this if it's not loaded client-side.

Comment: So why is it not accounted for in the granular page sizes?

Comment: Because those sizes are *SHARED BY ALL* ... so if route X is 368KB, and the JS shared by all is 195KB, you can reasonably infer that the remaining 173KB is specific to that route.

In this case for the `/` route, 12KB is loaded client-size (accounted for in the SIZE column), and the remaining 161KB is loaded server-side.

Comment: I have "First Load JS shared by all" 193 kB and "First Load JS" for many routes 178 kB which would make the Route-Specific Server-Side negative if I understood the logic correctly, so something is not adding up properly.

Comment: I have 15 kB css file so very likely "First Load JS shared by all" includes the css file but "First Load JS" does not include the css file even though both have JS in the name since 193 kB - 178 kB = 15 kB.